# bootstrap 4 with Angular 8: Navbar works, but doesn't auto-close on click (inside or outside navbar)

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am using ng-bootstrap with Angular 8 and I'm having a problem with the navbar. The navbar behaves correctly in terms of being responsive and opening/closing when clicking the hamburger icon, but the problem is that it does not "autoclose" when one of the links are clicked or when the user clicks "outside" of the navbar. It will only close if the user clicks on the hamburger again. Is there a way using ng-bootstrap to have the navbar autoclose on click?

```js
 isCollapsed = false;
```

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
      aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
      [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!--Logo-->
    <div class="sidebar-header d-none d-lg-block">
      <img src="assets/img/logo_color_cloudev.png" alt="cloudev-logo" />
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="isHide()"><i class="fa fa-desktop dash"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/roles" routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="this.isAdmin"><i class="fa fa-gg-circle icon"></i>Roles</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/users" routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="this.isAdmin"><i class="fa fa-users user"></i>Users</a>
        </li>
        <!--Dropdown-->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-line-chart leaves"></i><span>Leave Management</span>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/user-leaves" *ngIf="!this.isAdmin" routerLinkActive="active">My leaves</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="this.isAdmin" routerLink="/leave-types">Leave types</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="this.isAdmin" routerLink="/leave-request-admin">Leave Requests</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/holidays" routerLinkActive="active">Holidays</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <!--Toggle for header-->
        <div class="fullview">
          <hr class="d-block d-lg-none" />
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link d-block d-lg-none" routerLink="/my-profile" routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fa fa-user-md icon"></i>My profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link d-block d-lg-none" routerLink="/passwordchange" routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fa fa-key icon"></i>Reset password</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link d-block d-lg-none" (click)="logout()" routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fa fa-sign-out icon"></i>Logout</a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below attributes to close on the respective element

data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"